# USB type-B sockets vs USB Mini-B sockets

Tags: microcontroller, usb, integrated-circuit, usb-device, programmer

Most Programmers hardware equipped with **USB type-B** connectors for connecting to PC. **USB Mini-B** connectors are much less used in device programmers. Have the USB type-B connectors any advantages or benefits over USB Mini-B connectors when use in device programmers?

[image]

Comment: They don't snap off the pcb carrying the pads with them.

Comment: The theoretical rated mating cycles may appear to favor micro B, for example, but a through-hole Type B is about \$10^6\$ times more sturdy than a a tiny SMT part.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, "theoretical rated", yep... do you know that the difference between practice and theory is usually much bigger in practice than in theory? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mini-B was popular before the advent of Micro-B. Its downside is the tendency of the plug to get loose, as its relatively small, but doesn't have the hooks that Micro-B has.

So, it's mostly a mechanical thing. Since programmers (I assume you mean EEPROM programmers or something like that) are typically not as size-restricted as say, smartphones, you just use the larger, more durable plug. Makes sense to me. Also, that large plug is easier to handle.

Comment: Well, but I'm about comparision USB type-B vs USB Mini-B, not Micro-B. USB type-B is more durable, longer-lasting?

Comment: My point about micro-B is that it quickly superseeded mini-B because mini-B was so bad mechanically. "Is USB type-B more durable than mini-B?" well, yes, kind of directly resulting from the fact that every single component in a type-B is larger than its counterpart in mini-B (I mean, seriously, look at a mini-B plug. It's flimsy.)

Comment: The mounting shapes of both version on PCB are quite different, so we can't easily replace USB Mini-B with USB type-B?

Comment: @protone so what?

Comment: I mean is it difficult to replace existing USB Mini-B socket on board with USB type-B?

Comment: well, I don't understand that question. How difficult is it to replace one component with another one that has quite a different shape? I don't know, depends on who's doing that on what board under which restrictions with what tools under what time pressure.

Answer (score 0):

> Have the USB type-B connectors any advantages or benefits over USB Mini-B connectors when use in device programmers?

No electrical benefit. All differences are physical or aesthetics.

But not all are large Type B, the ST Link has Mini-B.

[image: st link]

Comment: I find somewhere that USB Mini-B have lifetime of of 5,000 connects/disconnects cycles, did't find such details for USB type-B.

Comment: 5000 really isn't great, and you can't have looked very far. For example, this Type-B receptable [datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/18/61729-1363119.pdf) specifies a variant for 12,000 plug cycles. Also, watch what you're asking: the amount of times a connector can be plugged says nothing about what happens to the PCB it's mounted on. And from a very simple mechanical consideration, it's pretty obvious that the smaller the connector footprint, the worse the effect on the PCB must be.

Comment: (Note, though, that 5000 is more than you'd ever need. I don't know, if you design a product that has to be plugged in more than 10 times a workday, you've probably built something that should have reset logic or less bugs)